# squid make error about libltdlc.la on compile

Tags: squid

I encounter a error when I was execute make. 
  The environment is
  1. OS X 10.10.5
  2. compiler is gcc ( I am not sure and make command log shows gcc many times)
  3. Squid source version 3.5.13

log as this:

```
./libtool: line 4228: cd: /Users/lorancechen/version: No such file or directory  
libtool: link: (cd .libs/libltdlc.lax/dlopen.a && ar x "/Users/lorancechen/version control/_open_source/squid-3.5.13/libltdl/./.libs/dlopen.a")  

./libtool: line 1085: cd: .libs/libltdlc.lax/dlopen.a: No such file or directory  

make[2]: *** [libltdlc.la] Error 1

make[1]: *** [all] Error 2

make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

===============================
Besides, I am not find .libs directory with log reminded.

**UPDATE**
with @Tibidabo help, I find the directory can't contains "." or "-".
Now, another error occurred, such as

```
basic_ldap_auth.cc:610:13: error: 'ldap_unbind' is deprecated: first deprecated
      in OS X 10.10 - use ldap_unbind_ext [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            ldap_unbind(ld);
            ^
```

I attempt change to `ldap_unbind_ext`, compiler tips with **can't find it** or **no known**.

Answer (score 2):

Please check that the directory does not have any "funny" characters.
I have the same error, I renamed the directory to have only alphanumerical characters by removing ".","-" etc and after that the make worked just fine!

Comment: another error occurred most of them is function deprecated, I have attempt fix it with tips of compiler.Anyhow,you are right but how about those problem?